# regarding a Vim regular expression to delete trailing spaces in each line

Tags: regex, vim

```
:%s/[ ]*$//g
```

Why does the regular expression above squeeze >=1 spaces at the end of any line to exactly one  but not 0 spaces?

Comment: Each time I additionally run `:%s/[ ]//g` after executing the command above to get rid of trailing spaces.

Comment: When I tried the regex you provided in my vim (running on Mac Snow Leopard), I ended up with zero trailing spaces. That said, you could try changing the * to a + (since there's no sense in replacing "" with ""), but I doubt that will help you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your regex works. There are no spaces left at the end of the line after you run it.

What you probably see is the "residual" incremental highlighting that would go away if you used
`:%s/[ ]\+$//g`. — Note the `\+` instead of the `*`. the incremental highlighting remains because `*` *always* matches, even with zero spaces.

To remove the highlighting, type `:noh` (short for `:nohlsearch`).

FYI: `:%s/[ ]*$//g` is equivalent to `:%s/ *$//g`.

Comment: Thanks. It's "residual" highlighting indeed. Those are no real spaces.

Comment: Also another way to specify the spaces is \s instead of [ ] and that will match both tabs and spaces.  You also don't need the g option since you are only doing one replacement per line.  You would end up with :%s/\s\+$//   Adding the g doesn't hurt though and I do it all the time just out of habit :)

Comment: @Neg Good point about the `g`. I do that all the time as well, but strictly speaking it *is* superfluous.

Comment: @Neg_EV Plain space (`%sm/ \+$//`) also works. I never saw trailing tabs.